# Alamofire4 jsonSerializationFailed in response

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I use Alamofire4 and I have a jsonSerializationFailed error in responseJson.
It seems that the response is not well formatted Json :

```
AlmF Failure Reason: jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo=
{NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})
AlmF Underlying error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})
```

Here is the code displaying there error:

```
case .responseSerializationFailed(let reason):
                    print("AlmF Response serialization failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    print("AlmF Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                }
```

Here is the result of debugPrint(response) for

```
 .responseJSON { response in:
```

=>

```
 [Request]: http://myserver.com/Images.zip
 [Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000003cde0> { URL: http://myserver.com.com/Images.zip } { status code: 200, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 117127;
"Content-Type" = "application/zip";
Date = "Tue, 01 Nov 2016 21:28:23 GMT";
Etag = "\"701a02b-1c987-534eb9a863980\"";
"Last-Modified" = "Fri, 10 Jun 2016 12:23:18 GMT";
Server = Apache;
"X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
```

Where should I format the Json, I thought Alamofire do that

Edit :

Before my code with Swift2 was:

```
.response { _, _, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                SpeedLog.print("DownloadVC Failed with error: \(error)")
            } else {
                SpeedLog.print("DownloadVC zip downloaded")
}
```

Comment: the response is not JSON but is a zip file, this is why serialization is failing in this case. I would check what your trying to achieve here since it is a file of what looks like zipped up images you're trying to download.

Comment: I am using Alamofire to download zip files and I thought I could use the errors managing for download also. The migration guide is not very clear for me : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#errors

Comment: I have added old code in my question